# measure on the boundary

Tags: functional-analysis

When dealing with an open bounded (connected if need be) subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the boundary is of measure zero with respect to lebesgue measure on the ambiant space ($\mathbb{R}^n$)

My first question would be why (intuitively it is but what exact result states it)

secondly when defining the trace operator onto $L^2(\partial \Omega)$, do we endow the boundary with a measure derived from the $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ lebesgue measure ? because otherwise the boundary is of measure $0$ wtr to that of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Thanks for any clarifications.

Comment: Note that $(0,1)$ with a fat Cantor set deleted is an open bounded set whose boundary has positive measure. I'm not sure whether this can be imitated when the open set in question is required to be connected. Of course it can't if the boundary is regular.

Comment: As for the trace, $\partial \Omega$ really gets the Hausdorff measure inherited from $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Lebesgue measure. For "nice" domains (i.e. those with sufficiently regular boundary) this looks locally like the $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ Lebesgue measure, i.e. "surface area" (if the $\mathbb{R}^n$ Lebesgue measure is understood as "volume").

Comment: @Ian If the open set shall be connected, then of course the boundary is a null set if the ambient space is $\mathbb{R}$, since the open connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are the open intervals. In higher dimension, the complement of a product of fat Cantor sets in the unit cube is connected.

Comment: So in view of Daniel Fischer's comment, in dimension greater than 1 there are open, bounded, connected sets whose boundary has positive measure. So you're going to need to add another hypothesis if you want to prohibit that.